# Pyomo ModelFactory (Model of several submodels) Design with OOP

Tags: python-3.x, oop, pyomo

I have written models in pyomo that can solve correctly when input with different types of parameters. Now, I want to solve several of these models simultaneously within an optimization problem. I'd like to do this in an OOP approach without re-writing a lot of code. Is this possible?

I've tried many of the block add_component() and block del_component() methods to copy attributes, but I haven't gotten this to work.

After importing and setting up my solver

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
solver = pyo.SolverFactory('ipopt')
```

I create a model class below

```
class Model(pyo.ConcreteModel):
    """
    Model that solves the trivial equation $xy=z$,
        where $x$ is a variable and $y$ and $z$ are parameters.
    """
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """

        :param kwargs: keyword arguments that become attributes of model
        """
        pyo.ConcreteModel.__init__(self)
        self.x = pyo.Var()
        self.y = pyo.Param(initialize=kwargs['y'])
        self.z = pyo.Param(initialize=kwargs['z'])
        self.constr = pyo.Constraint(expr=self.x*self.y==self.z)
        self.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=1.)
```

The model class here sets up an extremely simple problem to solve.

Now, I want to solve several of these models simultaneously using the ModelFactory class below.

```
class ModelFactory(pyo.ConcreteModel):
    """
    class that contains many Model classes and combines them into
        one single pyomo model that can be solved
    """
    def __init__(self, y_params, z_params):
        """

        :param y_params: values for parameters of y values for Model class
        :type y_params: list
        :param z_params: values for parameters of z values for Model class
        :type z_params: list
        """
        pyo.ConcreteModel.__init__(self)

        for i in range(len(y_params)):
            model_instance = Model(y=y_params[i], z=z_params[i])
            objects = list(
                model_instance.component_objects()
            )
            for obj in objects:
                if str(obj) in self.__dict__:
                    # common attributes in pyo.ConcreteModel
                    continue
                # copy and re-name all objects except the objective function
                if not isinstance(obj, pyo.Objective):
                    setattr(self, str(obj) + '_%i'%i , obj)
        self.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=1.)
```

I test the code with the following

```
inst = ModelFactory([0, 4, 3, 2], [100, 22, 4, 2])  # initialize with arbitrary data
    solver.solve(inst, tee=True)
```

I keep getting errors with the `setattr` command. 
One of the errors is

```
This behavior is not supported by Pyomo; components must have a
single owning block (or model), and a component may not appear
multiple times in a block.  If you want to re-name or move this
component, use the block del_component() and add_component() methods.
```

Is it possible to do this, or is it extremely complicated with del_component and add_component?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the use case, but I think what you are trying to do is probably easiest through an indexed block, with each block being initialized with different data. You can diversify the data by leveraging namespaces.

Comment: I agree with @GiorgioBalestrieri that an Indexed Block would be the best way to do this. You could reuse a single construction rule to build each index. I would also recommend using a containment design pattern and have a class that contains a Pyomo model instead of inheriting off of `ConcreteModel` directly. Inheriting off of Pyomo components is really tricky to get right if you're not intimately familiar with the core of Pyomo.